# how to prevent user from entering decimal values in integer fields in REST APIs in spring in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

Spring is automatically converting Decimal values to Integers while sending data through body of POST Method in REST APIs. While, I want to throw a custom exception if user enters Decimal values. Is there any easy way to do this.

Eg:: If user enters **age = 4.3** , then Spring is converting it to **4**.

Comment: JSON has no concept of a distinction between integers and floating-point.

Comment: The question doesn't contain enough details,.. how are you taking the data? post body? or pathvariable?

Comment: Hi Amanuel, I am using post body to post the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (age instanceof Integer) //dowork();
else //throw custom exception
```

consider age as type Object and then use the above code to do your testing.

Comment: Hi dtrihinas, thanks for your reply. But, I don't want to change my Model/POJO. Because, then it would lead to a lot of changes in my entire code. Can you please suggest some other way of doing it.

Comment: Because of java strict typing if you dont want to change the pojo you are better of doing this in the frontend right at your form... I think thymleaf has something for this

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is a way of preventing user from entering decimal numbers in place of an integer. You can do it this way.

```
@JsonProperty("age")
@NotNull
@Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
@Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 0)
private BigDecimal age;
```

Basically, you should change the type from **int** to the **BigDecimal**, becasue BigDecimal itself supports **@Digits** annotation, and this way, you can limit the field to only accept 0 decimal points as this example shows. If the user entered decimal value instead of integer, he will recieve **400 Bad Request**.